# How to reference a foreign key in html django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

```
{% for cred in allcreds %}
              {% if cred.datasource.name == '...' %}
              <h4>{{ cred.datasource }}</h4>
              {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

In this case I check the datasource name in the conditional. Then it prints out the datasource. I want to have the datasource in the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

I assume if you print out `{{ cred.protocoldatasource }}` it will output nothing, because your "relation" `protocoldatasource` does not exist.

The available foreign-keys that your model `ProtocolUserCredentials` has are: `protocol`, `data_source`, `user`, `protocol_user`.

So if you do

```py
{% if cred.data_source.name == 'Demonstration Protocol, ...' %}
```

or any other of the mentioned relations you can access your related models.

Also note that `{% if foo = 'bar' %}` is invalid, you'll need to have `==` in the if-statement.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response. So I understand the logic behind this but its still not displaying username and password for a cred object that has that data source i mentioned. I checked my admin and there is a protocol that has a data source named 'Demonstration Protocol, External Identifiers, demo_exrecs'. Maybe its something to do with the syntax of the string

Comment: @MPagan for testing purposes you could try matching against the `primary_key`, e.g. `if cred.data_source.pk == X`, where `X` is the pk of your object.

Comment: so that test does work and it prints out every objects username and password on the form. I just want to filter based on a certain datasource, wondering instead of using an if that i could just do ProtocolUserCredentials.objects.filter(protocoldatasource__data_source.name='Demonst...') in the view? And then obviously the same thing iterate in the template and print out u & p.

Comment: @MPagan yes, you can do that. Checking against the `pk` was just meant to be a test so you can be sure that the string you are checking against isn't the same as stored in the database. The correct filter as you said would be: `.filter(data_source__name='Deoms..')`

Comment: Oh ok I understand. So that filter isnt working, do you think it could be that since the data source is separated by commas that that is the error?

Comment: I can't tell you, as it is a string you should be able to just compare it. Maybe just copy it directly from your DB and compare the values. If it's not working I'd recommend you to open up a new question on SO for that specific problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! I'll be using that primary key test in the future for comparisons that was pretty useful

Comment: Just be careful that the primary_key can vary of course, so if you change your order of creating the credentials, it won't be the same.

Comment: Also please consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped with your problem at all, thanks!